# coding find from _underscore.js from scratch

Tags: javascript, arrays, find, underscore.js

As an exercise in higher order functions, I am attempting to code the entire underscore JS library from scratch. I am stuck on the following

```
var find = function(array, predicate) {
return reduce(array, function (previous,current) {
    if (previous !== undefined) {
        return previous;
    }
    else if (predicate(current) === true)
        {return current};

}, undefined)
```

}

My forEach and reduce functions:

```
var forEach = function(collection, callback) {
    if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++)
            callback(collection[i], i, collection);
    }
    else {
        for (var i in collection) {
            callback(collection[i], i, collection);
        }
    }
};

var reduce = function(collection, callback, startValue) {
    forEach(collection, function (element) {
        if (startValue !== undefined) {
            startValue = callback(startValue, element);
        }
        else {
            startValue = element;
        }
    });
    return startValue;
}
```

I used the following predicate function to test:

```
var isOdd = function(x) { 
    if (x%2 === 1) {
        return true
        }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

you'll see that the function find returns the first value in an array rather than the first odd number in the array.

what's most interesting is that when I write the function with the original arr.reduce function like so:

```
var finder = function(arr, test){
  return arr.reduce(function(memo, curr){
    if (memo === undefined){
      if (test(curr)){return curr;}
    }
    return memo;
  },undefined);
};
```

any ideas?

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: find in its current iteration is not working. why?

The Find function currently outputs the first value in the array rather than the first value that passes the predicate function with value true

Comment: Underscore, uh, has annotated source available.

Comment: true, but the annotated source does not code it with reduce. additionally, it's written for both objects and arrays

Comment: There is a reason it is not coded with reduce - it is inefficient.

Comment: fair point. haha. but IF I wanted to be inefficient and code it with reduce anyway, it should be possible. it just bothers me that the function isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT after a bit of thought: At start, because `startValue` is `undefined`, `startValue = element` (i.e. the first element of the array). After that, your callback gets called, but since `previous` is not `undefined` (and is, in fact, the first element in the array), it returns `previous` (the first element in the array).

Also, note that if your callback ever returns `undefined`, your `reduce` will do the wrong thing. If a starting value is not provided, you should call callback and start from the second element, outside the loop, or trigger this behaviour in the loop on index being `0`.

Comment: I believe reduce is being called on each element for as long as startValue is undefined.

efficiency issues aside, is there a reason why find traverses the entirety of the array, but still only returns the first value?